# Difference between HTTP Authorization header and Query string parameters

Tags: authentication, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, httprequest, pre-signed-url

While I was reading about interaction with `Amazon S3`, I came to know that request authentication with `Amazon AWS` is done in 2 ways

1. [HTTP Authorization](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html):
   Using the HTTP Authorization header is the most common method of providing authentication information
2. [Query string parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-query-string-auth.html):
   Using query parameters to authenticate requests is useful when you want to express a request entirely in a URL. This method is also referred as presigning a URL.

The question is in which situation should I prefer one method over the other. Do these two authentication methods have their own advantages and disadvantages? As a developer, by using `query string parameters` method I can presign the URL which enables the end users to temporarily access the `Amazon S3` resources by entering the presigned URL in the web browser. Can I use `HTTP Authorization` method to achieve the same thing? If so which method is better to use and what are their respective limitations?

Answer (score 4):

> Can I use HTTP Authorization method to achieve the same thing?

Sometimes.  The key difference is that, as a developer, you don't always have enough control over the user agent to inject a header.  The most obvious example of this is a simple `GET` request launched by a web browser in response to the user clicking a link.  In that situation, you don't have the a ability to inject an `Authorization:` header for the browser to send ... so pre-signing the URL is all you can do.

Importantly, there's no information in a signed URL that is considered sensitive, so there's no particularly strong motivation to use the header instead of a signed URL.  Your AWS Access Key ID is not secret, and your AWS Secret can't be derived from the other elements and the signature in a computationally-feasible time frame, particularly if you use Signature Version 4, which you should.  Signature Version 2 is not officially deprecated in older regions, but newer S3 never supported it and likely never will.

When you do control the user agent, such as in back-end server code, adding the header may be preferable, because you don't need to do any manipulation of the URL string you already have in-hand.

Comment: I have seen Amazon Cognito and I think its going to replace query string parameters by a new mechanism.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't *think* so... cognito, to my knowledge, generates temporary access keys and secrets that work like ordinary credentials with the addition of a security token.

Answer (score 1):

The overview in the [first AWS page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-auth-using-authorization-header.html) says what the difference is:

> Except for **POST requests** and **requests that are signed by using query parameters**, all Amazon S3 bucket operations and object operations use the Authorization request header to provide authentication information.

Basically a `POST` is used for [HTML **forms**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) (discussed at length in the Mozilla page).  You would use forms whenever the request involves passing data to the remote server, versus just checking status. As noted in *[HTML  method Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp)* (W3Schools),

> Never use `GET` to send sensitive data! (will be visible in the URL)

as distinguished from `POST`:

> Appends form-data inside the body of the HTTP request (data is not shown is in URL)